# COGNOS 11.1.3 - Drop down prompt disable parameter name and dotted line

Tags: cognos, cognos-11, report-studio

I have a question about value prompt in Cognos 11.1.3. I have a required value prompt with selected drop down UI. Prompt is using static choices.

The problem is that in Cognos 11.0.3 we disabled showing of parameter name and dotted line in UI by setting Header Text to empty value. Unfortunately this setting does not work after report upgrade to Cognos 11.1.3

Do you have any recommendation how to hide parameter name and dotted line options in drop down value prompt? I know there was an option to use javascript for that but I would like to avoid that. I prefer setting in Cognos.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just had a quick look and in 11.1.3 I can still remove the prompt name above the dotted line by setting the Header text to a blank using the interactive viewer.  The dotted line appears to be immune to this setting unless I switch the interactivity to No.

To do this click on the Report object,  then in the top right properties ensure the Run with full interactivity is set to No.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer.

Unfortunately I have to let report interactivity set to Yes because since Cognos 11 upgrade we start to use Custom Controls which doesn't work when the report interactivity is set to No. 

But the interesting thing is, that parameter name line has disappeared when you have Header Text set to blank in your Cognos environment. That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Odd, not sure why your test would be different.  I was using Chrome and as a quick test I just created a single value prompt with 1 static use and display value.  This was done as a new report.